# Converting an array into a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Can anyone explain me how an array is converted into a `Hash` here?

```
puts Hash[*[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]
```

I am not understanding what `happens` behind when we call `Hash[*[]]].flatten]`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do :

```
Hash[[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']]]
# => {:first_name=>"Shane", :last_name=>"Harvie"}
```

Look at the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) syntax :

```
Hash[ key, value, ... ] → new_hash 
Hash[ [ [key, value], ... ] ] → new_hash
```

If you do use `faltten` then below is the result :-

```
[[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]
# => [[:first_name, "Shane", :last_name, "Harvie"]]
```

If you do use *splat* with `faltten` then you would get below :

```
[*[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]
# => [:first_name, "Shane", :last_name, "Harvie"]
```

Now, `Hash[*[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]` will give you the hash, as my top code gives. but you don't need to do this much work, as `Hash` *documentation* clearly matches with your input data, so only `Hash[input_data]` is enough.

Comment: What does * indicate there?

Comment: @Shane this is [splat operator](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2012/01/splat-operator-in-ruby.html)

Answer (score 2):

`Hash` class defines a method `[]`. This methods takes any number of arguments, takes each pair and creates a new hash with first element of each pair being keys and the second element being a value. If you pass odd amount ov arguments, this will fail. Also it allows you to pass 2d array or any number of 2 element arrays.

Now you have 2d array: `[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']]`. When you call flatten, you merge all the inner arrays in one:

```
Hash[[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]
Hash[[:first_name, 'Shane', :last_name, 'Harvie']]
```

Now if you use splat operator, you extract all the elements and pass them to `[]` method as separate arguments, so this transaltes to:

```
Hash[*[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]
Hash[:first_name, 'Shane', :last_name, 'Harvie']
```

Note however that it is not needed - `Hash[]` can deal with the initial form. Just do:

```
Hash[[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

First the array is flattened:

```
[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten
# becomes: [:first_name, 'Shane', :last_name, 'Harvie']
```

Since the [`Hash#[]` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) accepts an arbitrary number of parameters like so

```
Hash['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

and not an array you need to use the splat operator (`*`) to expand the array on the stack so the values get used as parameters

```
Hash[*[:first_name, 'Shane', :last_name, 'Harvie']]
# becomes: Hash[:first_name, 'Shane', :last_name, 'Harvie']
```

And Arup is right, you don't need the flatten, because the `Hash#[]` method accepts 2d arrays as well.

Answer (score 1):

What we get without using of splat * :--

```
[[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]
#=> [[:first_name, "Shane", :last_name, "Harvie"]]
```

So here you get a 2D array and '' => "".

Now, let's see what we get with splat * being used:--

```
[*[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]
#=> [:first_name, "Shane", :last_name, "Harvie"]
```

Here you get 1D array, so splat has caused the inner array to come out of its container array.

So `Hash[*[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]` is same to `Hash[:first_name, "Shane", :last_name, "Harvie"]`

```
#=> {:first_name=>"Shane", :last_name=>"Harvie"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[*[[:first_name, 'Shane'], [:last_name, 'Harvie']].flatten]
```

The best thing we can do is to start from the inside and then go outwards.

In the innermost part you have two arrays that have two elements each:
A symbol and a string.

Going for the next set of brackets, we have an array that contain those two arrays.

`flatten` will flatten the two arrays inside, so that we have one array containg for elements, instead of an array containing another two arrays.

The star(*) operator, expands an array into a list of arguments to be used in a function.

So

`[:first_name, 'Shane', :last_name, 'Harvie']`

will turn into

`:first_name, 'Shane', :last_name, 'Harvie'`

the last part is Hash[]

which is a function that takes an array of parameters and turns them into a Hash.

`{:first_name=>'Shane', :last_name=>'Harvie'}`

Voila. It's simpler than it looked at first.

**Observations:**

If you take a look at the documentation of Hash, you'll see that you could have just passed multiple arrays to Hash[] and it would take care of it.

**References:**

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-2A
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-flatten

Comment: -1. You wrote as if `*` turns `[:first_name, 'Shane', :last_name, 'Harvie']` into `[:first_name=>'Shane', :last_name=>'Harvie']`, but the notation `[:first_name=>'Shane', :last_name=>'Harvie']` represents a hash enclosed in an array, which means that `*` by itself did the array to hash conversion. This is clearly wrong.

Comment: Also your **A symbol and a literal (string)**, is inconsistent. They are a symbol and a string, both a literal.

Comment: sawa: Will fix the notation cause that was not what I meant. and the symbol/literal thing too.

Comment: sawa: Done. Got it fixed. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Sorry for that. Fixed :)